# Using rvest to scrape GoodReads pages

Tags: html, r, web-scraping, rvest

I'm trying to scrape ratings and review numbers on goodreads, but getting an NA result. Why is this?

SelectorGadget finds "span span" for the average rating on hover over, but there's no "valid path" found at the bottom.

Using the same method on other sites (e.g. IMDB, theatlantic.com) works fine.

Here's my code and result (I've also tried replacing html_text with html_tag)

```
 Rating<- html("http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/22444789-delicious-foods")

Rating %>%
 html_node("span span") %>%
 html_text () %>%
 as.numeric()
[1] NA
Warning message:
In function_list[[k]](value) : NAs introduced by coercion
```

Comment: Scraping the site is a violation of their [terms of service](http://www.goodreads.com/about/terms). Anyone who helps you is in violation of that TOS and you are also in violation of that TOS. They have an [API](http://www.goodreads.com/api/index). If that's not sufficient, you should contact them for explicit permission to use their data first.

Comment: ok then I guess I'll stick to their API

Comment: good to see we have users on here white knighting ToS lol what a joke

Answer (score 1):

I didn't have any success using selectorgadget with the Goodreads site, but sometimes you just have to look at the html source and find what you're looking for that way.

In this case, you can use the .average class selector:

```
Rating %>%
 html_node(".average") %>%
 html_text %>%
 as.numeric
```